# Changing URL of scripts, scripts outside theme folder?

Tags: themes, wp-enqueue-script, scripts

Is it possible to have css and js scripts **outside of template directory**? If it is possible, how can I achieve it?

Basically, instead of having:

```
http://example.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/assets/mystyle.css
```

I want to have:

```
http://example.com/assets/mystyle.css
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can enqueue JS and CSS from anywhere - even other sites. However, your theme will have to have a "style.css" with at minimum the required comments for WP to recognize it as a theme that can be activated.

Comment: I didn't quite get it. I have WP installed inside the root folder (public_html). The structure of WP files is normal wp-admin, wp-content,... I don't want to have scripts inside root/wp-content/themes/mytheme, but I want them to be outside theme folder. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Place them wherever you want, but enqueue them from `root/wp-content/themes/mytheme/functions.php` - just give the full server path to wherever you've put them.